# Unity FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I fix these errors when I try to build a project leaving these errors:

1)CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.

2)Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 287 seconds

3)UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ca] in <22954a70fcec46f29620f943d3d7bf23>:0
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <22954a70fcec46f29620f943d3d7bf23>:0
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

[image]

[image]

Comment: See 2nd error on bottm with red exclamation point.  Looks like either Android has issue of the Java install on machine needs updating.

Comment: @jdweng Can I then manually install the sdk?

Comment: @jdweng or should I just reinstall java?

Comment: Do not know.  Just know the OpenJDK is failing or one of its components.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you very much, right now I'll try

Answer (score -2):

Fixed the problem, when running Unity hub, please install the Android platform first.